# How to substitute variables with envsubst in Makefiles?

Tags: linux, sed, regular-expression, make

I want to substitute variables in my postfix template within Makefiles.

```
.PHONY: replace clean
export DOMAIN ?= home.lan
replace:
   @echo $(DOMAIN)
   envsubst   < template > main.cf
   cat out.test
```

my template file looks like:

```
...snip..
$myorigin = ${DOMAIN}
$mydomain = $myorigin
```

executing make gives me output like this, replacing ${DOMAIN} variable, but also replacing $mydomain variable as well $myorigin key :

```
= home.lan
=
```

With shell scripts in past I was doing something like this:

```
VARS='$API_URL'
envsubst "$VARS" < /etc/nginx/template > /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

and $API_URL was properly replaced with env one. How can I do this with Makefiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use '$${DOMAIN}'

```
.PHONY: replace
export DOMAIN ?= home.lan
replace:
    envsubst '$${DOMAIN}' < template
```

run:

```
make replace
```

output:

```
envsubst '${DOMAIN}' < template
...snip..
$myorigin = home.lan
$mydomain = $myorigin
```